# How to make a automatic slideshow using javascript with fading?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OJBk.png)

I would like the photos to replace and fade after a time interval but currently, it is only able to fade in and out and the image are stack on top of one another.

The js code:

```js
var current = 0,
  slides = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

setInterval(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
  current = (current != slides.length - 1) ? current + 1 : 0;
  slides[current].style.opacity = 1;
}, 3000);


  
The html code:
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="background1">
  <!--Section to display content-->
  <section id="content">
    <!-- Images used to open the lightbox -->
    <figure><img class="img-fluid" src="../Others/daylight-environment-forest-459225.jpg"></figure>
    <figure><img class="img-fluid" src="../Others/nature-sky-twilight-grass-9198.jpg"> </figure>
    <!--Display content-->
    <div class="content">
      <p class="small">Sustainability</p>
      <p class="big">Starts with<br> You</p>
      <a href="../Website/about.html">Learn more!</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
<script src="../bootstrap/slideshow.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<!--jquery library-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--popper js-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!--Latest compiled js-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using JavaScript for opacity... How about using just css to control the opacity & give you the fading effect that you're aiming for... like in the **snippet** below:

```css
/* Make the image fully responsive */

.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  animation: fadeAway 6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0
}

@keyframes fadeAway {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src=https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ "ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```